# Login Github with Curl

Tags: authentication, curl, github

I tried call this command

```
curl -l -u "my_user_name" https://my-enterprise-github.com
```

Then, I input my password manually.

But it returns this

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://my-enterprise-github.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-enterprise-github.com%2F">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Please explain what's wrong with my command. 
Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to get after you 'log in'?

Comment: @osowskit Well, I want to get some information in my pull request

Comment: Would using the API be easier? What information

Comment: @osowskit I want to use this API but I don't know how to use it with curl
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL should not be used for access to GitHub's (or most web) UI without specific reasons. GitHub provides an API to allow accessing data as a well-defined structure.

You mentioned wanting to [get-a-single-pull-request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request). This relies on a URL pattern following `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number`.

So if you had a GitHub account, [`facebook`](https://github.com/facebook), and wanted to look up a specific pull request [`15947`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15947) in [`react-native`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native). The full URL would be

`https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react-native/pulls/15947`

The cURL command would be

```
curl -u osowskit -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react-native/pulls/15947
```

Note that:

1. You will likely want to start using a PAT or OAuth token instead of username/password
2. There are tools that make exploring the GitHub API easier. [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or octokit

Answer (score 1):

To start with you may want the `-L` flag.  From the [cURL Frequently Asked Questions](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT)

> #### 3.8 How do I tell curl to follow HTTP redirects?
>
> Curl does not follow so-called redirects by default. The Location: header that informs the client about this is only interpreted if you're using the -L/--location option. As in:
>
> ```
> curl -L http://redirector.com
> ```
>
> Not all redirects are HTTP ones, see 4.14

Comment: Thank for your answer. I wonder how to get information of a pull request in curl command? I read this document but I don't know how to call the API properly 
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request

Comment: [A curl tutorial using GitHub's API](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: NOTE: jq's lnk (granted almost 5 years old) is no longer working....

Answer (score 0):

There's also a CLI now that can be helpful for many similar use-cases:

https://cli.github.com/

```
$ gh pr list
Showing 2 of 2 open pull requests in Roblox/service-comms-nomad

#16  chi1 Traefik 1.7 GLB jobs  chi1-glb-prep
#6   Cgt/t2                     cgt/t2
```