# curl command failing to download release asset from private GitHub repo

Tags: github, curl, token, github-api, release

According to multiple answers provided in other similar questions, I am trying to download a release assed from GitHub using `curl`, as follows:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX" -LJO https://github.com/Org/repo/releases/download/0.4.2/repo-linux-amd64
```

This keep fetching a file with content `Not Found`.

When opening the link `https://github.com/Org/repo/releases/download/0.4.2/repo-linux-amd64` from an authenticated browser window, it does download the file.

I have also tested my `token` by running

```
curl -H "Authorization: token XXXXXXXX" https://api.github.com/user
```

What is more, the token has the right scopes given that

```
gh release download 0.4.2 --pattern repo-linux-amd64 -R Org/repo
```

also works (the token value is exported in the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable).

I have also tried this variation (with `token` instead of `Bearer` in the `Authorization` header) and the end result is the same

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" -H "Authorization: token XXXXXXXX" -LJO https://github.com/Org/repo/releases/download/0.4.2/repo-linux-amd64
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [Login Github with Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193799/login-github-with-curl) ?

Comment: Good idea, but how to find the [asset id](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-release-asset)